# Send array to viewcontroller iOS xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.5

I have 2 view controller:

Index
Second
In Index I have 2 textfield and button.

I fill this text field and press "next button" to second view, I need to "show" this two text field, by using Array (later I will send JSON data).

I Tried this: 
Declare an @property in class Second as textArray. And then while pushing to Second from Index, you need to set this property.

In Second.h file,

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *textArray;
```

In Index.m file,

```
Second *aSecond = [[Second alloc] init];
aSecond.textArray = @[textField1.text, textField2.text];
```

//write code to push from Index to Second
Now in class Second, you can use it as aSecond.textArray[0] and aSecond.textArray[1]

But if i switch page (click next) array has been nulled.

For switch page i use this:

```
SecondPage *SecondPage = [self.storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    SecondPage = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondPage"];
    [self SecondPage animated:YES];
```

How I can best realize? Please help! Best regards
Ivan.

Comment: Never give your class name as your instance variable name. It can cause many problems.

Comment: Did you alloc your array?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There are lot of ways to transfer the value from one controller to an other, but for you I think this will be the most simple ever. Use `NSUserDefaults`

First Easy Ways

in first Controller

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[textField1.text, textField2.text] forKey:@"listOfData"];
```

in 2nd Controller

```
NSArray *array = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"listOfData"];
```

2nd Easy ways is

```
DetailVC *detailVC = [self.storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
detailVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailVC"];
detailVC.textArray = @[textField1.text, textField2.text];
```

Comment: It might work, but it's just wrong the way you do it. It only enforces bad habits and spaghetti code. A person that comes to your code, should know just by looking for the Second `UIViewController` init methods, that in order for it to work, it should receive an `NSArray`. @pradeepa answer is much better than this.

Comment: @JackyBoy, How do you think answer by Pradeepa will work when he is instantiating `secondPage` as `secondPage = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondPage"];`. You cant use that code.

Answer (score 3):

Write your own designated initializer for second view controller something like.

```
-(id)initWithTextArray:(NSArray *)_textarray;
```

Now alloc init the second view controller

```
Second *aSecond = [[Second alloc] initWithTextArray:array];
```

in the viewDidLoad method of second view controller use your textarray to populate your views.

Comment: I think you should explain how this can be done using the code in question where he is using `secondPage = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondPage"];`. How will you do in that case?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it like this if you are using it via storyboard,

```
SecondPage *aSecondPage = [self.storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
aSecondPage = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondPage"];
aSecond.textArray = @[textField1.text, textField2.text];
[self aSecondPage animated:YES];
```

When you do this `aSecond = [[Second alloc] init];` and then do `aSecondPage = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondPage"];`, it is creating a separate instance and not the same instances. You were setting this array on the first one and expecting it to be set on the second instance.

Answer (score 0):

Hey had you tried for 'Global variable & Array with Delegate Method'. It'll not release till you'll remove. It'll be global till the application instance.

In Delegate Class,

.h File

```
NSMutableArray *obj;
```

.m file,

```
Synthesize & Alloc - init array.
```

Then,

In ViewContoller .m file

```
AppDelegate *app;
app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

then,

```
[app.obj addObject: text1.text];
```

In Second .m file, you can use it.

```
NSLog(@" Data : %@", app.obj);
```

Keep in mind, whenever you want this array, you should initialize 'app' object of 'Delegate' class.

It'll work & stores data globally.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two methods:

1) Either add a method in Second and after initializing call it and pass the value as an argument to a method. so in Second.m `-(void) push :(NSArray *)array{}` pass it with "&" before your NSArray name.

2) Create a getter in First. Since its NS, you have to use assign so in First.h you put `@property(nonatomic, assign) NSArray *array1;` 
In First.m you add the `@synthesize array1;`
and call it with 
`self.array1 = [@"t", @"e", @"s", @"t"];`
And then pass the reference to First class in Second and create a variable in Second.m and get it 
`NSArray *array1 = first.array1;`

You can write your own getter, but not reasonable.

Answer (score -2):

```
SecondPage *SecondPage = [self.storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    SecondPage = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondPage"];
    [self SecondPage animated:YES];
```

1) Your variable name and your class name are the same
2) I'm not sure XCode accepted that you wrote [self SecondPage animated:YES];

Finally, did you alloc your array ?

EDIT;

Oh and :

```
aSecond.textArray = @[textField1.text, textField2.text];
```

You should write:

```
[aSecond.textArray addObject:textField1.text]; // using NSMutableArray
```